# Get back the original value of width and height from rounded values

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

I have this calculation for resizing an image in my site.

Here is the sample code:

```
pw = 1600 //original width
ph = 1200 //original height
mw = 200  
mh = 200

ratio = mw / float(pw)
pw = mw
ph = float(ph)* ratio
```

The output of this and the new width and height of the resize image is:

```
pw = 200 //resize width
ph = 150 //resize height
```

Now my problem is I don't know how to calculate and get back the original value of height and width based on the given resize value.

Comment: math.floor is not a reversible operation. You can't get back to the original values based on the output values.

Comment: @JonathanRich `math.floor` is ok in the python code but because this is mathematics I understand what's your point so I remove that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just divide the new width and height by ratio.  In your case ratio$=0.125$, so $\frac {150}{0.125}=1200$ and $\frac {200}{0.125}=1600$  If you do use a floor, it will not be exact, but it will be close.

Comment: @catherine:  you have already calculated the ratio.  If you don't know that, you will need one of pw or ph.  Otherwise, there is nothing to set the scale.  You could expand 200x150 to 600x450 or 1600x1200 or 3200x2400 or ...  It is the same on your scale down.  If you didn't have mw=200 you wouldn't know how much to scale down.

Comment: yeah I know I already have calculated the ratio. My problem is if the resize image is save I can't get that ratio. The remaining I can have is the resize value. That's why I'm asking you how to calculate the ratio.

Comment: That code above is part of saving method for new resize image. So when it save, I cannot access that saving method anymore.

Comment: @catherine:  if there is nothing that tells you what size it came from, you can't get that information back again.  That was the point of my last comment.  It is like you divided $10$ by $5$ and got $2$.  You are now asking to know that the original was $10$ just from the answer $2$.

Comment: Yeah I know what's you're talking about my point is I can only have `200` and `150` for calculation (no values for original width, height, or ratio ) so if I divide the two value I get `.75` which is wrong. So I'm asking you how to get the ratio of `0.125`???

Comment: The 0.75 is the aspect ratio, which you are maintaining as you scale.  That is different from the scaling ratio.  What makes you think you can find the scaling ratio from the data you have?  If nobody had told you to scale from 1600x1200 to 200, how would you find the scaling ratio in that direction?

Comment: So in general, it's impossible... So I need to find another way. That's what I want to hear from you because I don't know what I'm going to do.